# difference between azure devops cloud and azure devops server 2019

Tags: azure-devops

I cannot find the below configuration in azure devops server (aka TFS)

Please find the below screenshots from azure devops where you can do exactly that

1- Add a public source

[image]

2- Add a custom npm registry

[image]

3- You can see folio added to upstreams
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhIX4.png)

So why do you think TFS 2019 can't do just that?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a new feature, Azure DevOps Service contain the latest feature and we could check the [timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline) in this site.

And Azure DevOps Server is updated once a period of time. If we check some new feature in the Azure DevOps Service and does not see it in the Azure DevOps, we need to check this [Azure DevOps Server 2019 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019u1?view=azure-devops) and wait for the update.